# How to organize repository when refactoring an existing project?

Tags: git

I'm currently working on an API built in PHP. My plan is to migrate it to Golang.

Should I start a brand new repository for this Golang version or just create a branch from the existing one in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there won't be any merge between branches of PHP code to branches of Go code, a new repository is cleaner.

You can reference the existing PHP repository as a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) within your new repository, in order to memorize the exact state of the PHP code for a given Go code-base commit.